# Use JS countdown timer in Canvas with requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, canvas, setinterval, countdown, requestanimationframe

I'm making a simple canvas- game and I'm using requestAnimationFrame (Paul Irish's version) for the gameloop. I'm using a javascript countdown in the game (showing seconds and 100th of seconds), but it doesn't count down in the right speed. I know this has to do with the refresh- rate of the game, so that the counter updates every frame instead of every 100th second. How do I fix this?

Here's the timer object:

```
/**
 * The timer as an object
*/
function Timer(position, time) {
  this.position = position || new Vector(150,210);
  this.time = time || 6000;
}

Timer.prototype = {
  start: function() {
    console.log('start running');
    this.initial = this.time; //time in 100'ths of seconds
    this.count = this.initial;
    this.counter; //10 will  run it every 100th of a second
    clearInterval(this.counter);
    //this.counter = setInterval(this.timer, 10);
    this.timer();
  },

  timer: function() {
    //console.log(this.count);
    this.count--;
      var res = this.count / 100;
    //Show counter in canvas
    return 'Tid kvar: ' + res.toPrecision(this.count.toString().length) + ' sekunder';
  },

  draw: function(ct) {
    if(this.initial === undefined){this.start();} //Start the timer
    ct.save();
    if(this.count <=0){ //Remove timer if timer has reached 0
      ct.clearRect(this.position.x, this.position.y, Racetrack.innerTrackWidth, Racetrack.innerTrackHeight);
      return false;
    } else { //draw timer
      ct.save();
      ct.font = 'bold 3em arial';
      ct.fillStyle = 'orange';
      ct.fillText(this.timer(), this.position.x, this.position.y);
    }
    ct.restore();
  }, 
}
```

And the gameloop and the part calling the timer:

```
  var init = function(canvas) {
    timer = new Timer(new Vector(160,210), 3000);
  }

  var render = function() {
    ct.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
    ship.draw(ct);
    racetrack.draw(ct);
    //draw timer or results if timer reached 0
    timer.draw(ct) !=false ? timer.draw(ct) : endFrame.draw(ct);
  };

  var gameLoop = function() {
    var now = Date.now();
    td = (now - (lastGameTick || now)) / 1000; // Timediff since last frame / gametick
    lastGameTick = now;
    if(timer.draw(ct) == false) { //stop the game if timer has reached 0.
      cancelRequestAnimFrame(gameLoop);
      console.log('Time\'s up!');
    } else { //Otherwise, keep the game going.
      requestAnimFrame(gameLoop);
    }
    update(td);
    render();
  };
```

I've also tried this as timer- object, but debugging `this.count` shows number the first loop, undefined the second loop and NaN every loop after that (And I'm not sure this will fix the timing issue either way?):

```
function Timer(position, time) {
  this.position = position || new Vector(150,210);
  this.time = time || 6000;
}

Timer.prototype = {
  start: function() {
    console.log('start running');
    this.initial = this.time; //time in 100'ths of seconds
    this.count = this.initial;
    this.counter; //10 will  run it every 100th of a second
    clearInterval(this.counter);
    this.counter = setInterval(this.timer, 10);
    this.timer();
  },


  timer: function() {
    console.log(this.count);
    this.count--;
  },

  getTime: function() {
    var res = this.count / 100;
    return 'Tid kvar: ' + res.toPrecision(this.count.toString().length) + ' sekunder';
  },

  draw: function(ct) {
    if(this.initial === undefined){this.start();} //Start the timer
    ct.save();
    if(this.count <=0){ //Remove timer if timer has reached 0
      ct.clearRect(this.position.x, this.position.y, Racetrack.innerTrackWidth, Racetrack.innerTrackHeight);
      return false;
    } else { //draw timer
      ct.save();
      ct.font = 'bold 3em arial';
      ct.fillStyle = 'orange';
      ct.fillText(this.getTime(), this.position.x, this.position.y);
    }
    ct.restore();
  },
}
```

Comment: requestAnimationFrame passes the time in ms to the function it calls as the first argument. `function myLoop(time){requestAnimationFrame(myLoop)}` Using `setInterval` especially with such a short interval is asking for trouble as anything that delays the browser for 1/100th of a second will end up with it trying to catch up and if you have an animation that takes near that time to render it will crash the browser. Avoid using `setInterval` for anything shorter than the browser my hang for.

Comment: @Blindman67 Any suggestions to how to solve this in another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you are asking to display the time in 1/100 intervals or if the time is inaccurate when using setInterval.

A: setInterval should not be used for timing, as it is far from accurate and gets worse the smaller the interval, and even worse if you have animations running.

B: Browser's refresh at 1/60th of a second. You can force the display to render and present at 1/100 of a second but then depending on the graphics hardware it may never be displayed because the display is scanning pixels elsewhere on the screen at the time. Or you will get shearing when you overwrite the display just as the graphics is being written to the display.

Best way to get a countdown using requestAnimationFrame

```
var start = true;     // flags that you want the countdown to start
var stopIn = 3000;    // how long the timer should run
var stopTime = 0;     // used to hold the stop time
var stop = false;     // flag to indicate that stop time has been reached
var timeTillStop = 0; // holds the display time

// main update function
function update(timer){

    if(start){  // do we need to start the timer
        stopTime = timer + stopIn; // yes the set the stoptime
        start = false;             // clear the start flag
    }else{                         // waiting for stop
        if(timer >= stopTime){     // has stop time been reached?
            stop = true;           // yes the flag to stop
        }
    }

    timeTillStop = stopTime - timer;      // for display of time till stop
    // log() should be whatever you use to display the time.
    log(Math.floor(timeTillStop / 10) );  // to display in 1/100th seconds

    if(!stop){
        requestAnimationFrame(update); // continue animation until stop 
    }
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);  // start the animation
```

Forgot to add.

You are never going to get 100th of a second accuracy via that method. You will be on average 7-8 ms out. But unless you make it far more complex that is the best you can do. That 7-8ms average is constant and the same for 2 hours and 1 second and is just determined by the animation refresh time of about 16 odd ms.

Comment: Thanks, seems good! One question, though: What does the parameter timer do? -No parameters are sent to the function, yet it takes this param. Where do it get its value?

Comment: @Sluggo Time is passed as an argument by the browser when it calls the callback function you set via `requestAnimationFrame`. It is the time in 1/1000th of a second and most browsers now have it accurate to 1,000,000th of a second through the extra precision is represented as a fractional component thus a value of 100.055 is 100,055/1,000,000th. Time is the time since the page started though when page start is I don't know. You can sync it to real time by compare it to `Date.now()` and using that offset for the life of the page.